# jQuery sortable - PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery sortable() to order images in a DB. The HTML is as follows.

```
<h2>Revision 1</h2>

<ul class='sortable'>
<li class='sortPhotos' id='item_249745' >
     <img src="../data/gallery/13387/images/album/1650519801.jpg"/>
     <p>1650519801.jpg</p>
</li>
<li class='sortPhotos' id='item_249744' >
     <img src="../data/gallery/13387/images/album/704633205.jpg"/>
     <p>704633205.jpg</p>
</li>
</ul>

<h3>Revision 2</h3>

<ul class='sortable'>
<li class='sortPhotos' id='item_518811' >
     <img src="../data/gallery/13387/images/album/001.jpg"/>
     <p>001.jpg</p>
</li>
<li class='sortPhotos' id='item_518812' >
     <img src="../data/gallery/13387/images/album/003.jpg"/>
     <p>003.jpg</p>
</li
</ul>
```

**The JS**

```
<script>

    $(".sortable").sortable({stop:function(i) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "../albumUploader/queries/sort.php",
                data: $(".sortable").sortable("serialize")
            });
        },
        opacity:1.0
    });    
</script>
```

**And finally the SQL**

```
foreach($_GET['item'] as $key=>$value) {

    mysql_query("   UPDATE galleryimage
                    SET sort = '{$key}'
                    WHERE id = '{$value}'  
                   ");
}
```

The issue with the above example -- the first revision is the only revision that is actually sorting in the DB. The other revision(s) are not. It does appear from monitoring the network in Chrome web developer extension that both lists are sending to the DB, but the second is not writing. Any ideas on this one?

Comment: I need to figure out how to give a unique id to each UL -- it seems sortable is only recognizing the first and not .sortable as a class

Comment: Wait - are both lists being sent to the PHP code or not?  Your answer seems to imply yes, but your comment seems to imply no.

Answer (score 0):

Each sortable needs to have it's own unique id. I resolved it with:

```
ul id='sortable_" . $count ."'
$count++;

$(".revisionNum").each(
        function(e) {
        num = e + 1;
        $("#sortable_" + num).sortable(
            {stop:function(i) {
                serial = $("#sortable_"  + num).sortable("serialize");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "../albumUploader/queries/sort.php",
                    data: serial
                });
            },
            opacity:1.0
        });    
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to only send one list to the server at a time.  This could be done by sending the data from `$(this)` instead of from `$(".sortable")`:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({stop:function(i) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "../albumUploader/queries/sort.php",
            data: $(this).sortable("serialize")
        });
    },
    opacity:1.0
});
```

Comment: I suppose I should qualify that while this sort of thing is standard across jQuery events, I have not actually tested it with this particular plugin.